# Do I need a transit visa at Hong Kong Airport?

Tags: canada, hong-kong, malaysia

I am a Syrian citizen. I want to travel from Canada to Malaysia with a transit in Hong Kong Airport. I have a Canadian Travel Document. Do I need a transit visa for Hong Kong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will [need a visa as a Syrian national](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html), unless:

- It is a *direct transit by air* and you do *not* leave the airport transit area throughout your transit; or
- Your Canadian Travel Document shows that you have another nationality (e.g. Canadian) eligible for visa-free entry to Hong Kong.